# Adapter not showing layout correctly

Tags: android, xml, adapter

OK, so I have created my custom ArrayAdapter and have defined a list_item.xml file which should, in theory, produce each row of my ListView to have a picture on the left, with two lines next to the picture (one with a contact name, and one with the contact phone number.) However, I currently only display the picture with the contact phone number on the line. Here is my ListAdapter code, and the list_item.xml code:

ListAdapter

```
package com.example.codingchallenge;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactInfo>{

private ArrayList<ContactInfo> contacts;
private ArrayList<PhoneNumber> numbers;
private final Context context;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap;

public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps, ArrayList<ContactInfo> contacts) {
    //Call to Super
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, contacts);

    //Assign variables
    this.context = context;
    this.bitmap = bitmaps;
    this.contacts = contacts;
    numbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();

    // Grab the PhoneNumber objects out of the contacts ArrayList
    for(ContactInfo contact: contacts) {
        numbers.add(contact.getPhone());
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    //Inflate the layout for our Adapter
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    //Instantiate different views
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView phoneNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

    //Set the image and text as what we want
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(position));
    name.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
    phoneNumber.setText(numbers.get(position).getWork());

    return view;
}

}
```

And list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea why the name line is not showing up in my layout?

Comment: add `android:layout_below="@id/name"` in your Phonenumber `TextView`

Comment: That throws an error saying circular layouts cannot exist in a relative layout, I'm assuming sine I already define the Name TextView to be below the PhoneNumber one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Layout` it's perfect working in my case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This worked but for some reason, the phoneNumber TextView is now on top of the name TextView.

Comment: @BillL but in my case it shows name TextView in top and it's perfect

Comment: Are you using the same ListAdapter code as me? I wonder what goes wrong on my end then.

Comment: @BillL ya same to same. It's very strange.

Comment: That's extremely strange, I wonder if something went wrong in another piece of code somewhere, although I can't possibly think of what.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"           
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's what I just tried and got the error that circular layouts cannot exist in relative layouts.

Comment: That's still displaying the name TextView on bottom. I think something else is wrong in the Adapter now. This is the third time that the name TextView has been on bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Put Both TextView inside LinearLayout and give LinearLayout this property android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail". It will solve your problem.

Comment: Keep it all inside of the RelativeLayout and just nest a LinearLayout? Or should I change my entire layout to Linear and move the ImageView outside of that?

Comment: Keep Relative Layout, and put LinearLayout inside it. Nested Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```